# Get all geom points that are more than 3 meters from the linestring, at big scale

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, geometry, linestring, osmosis

With the help of Osmosis i was able to import all the data of a Open Street Map city, (Nodes, ways, etc...).
In another table at same db, i have Millions locations in that city, these locations are also geom points.

The image below shows a way that is a linestring and the green dots represents locations that are geom points.

[image]

Is it possible to query at really big scale without iterating over each location, to get all the locations *(geom points)* that are more than 3 meters away from its closest way (**linestring**) within a all the ways i have in the db?

My first approach was this query

```
SELECT locations.geom FROM locations
JOIN ways
ON ST_DWithin(
        (ways.linestring)::geography,
        (locations.geom)::geography,
3) = false;
```

and

```
SELECT locations.geom FROM locations,ways
WHERE ST_DWithin(
    (ways.linestring)::geography,
    (locations.geom)::geography,
    3) = false;
```

with these two indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ways_geography_cast_gpx ON ways USING GIST (geography(ways.linestring));
CREATE INDEX locations_geography_cast_gpx ON locations USING GIST (geography(locations.geom));
```

But it takes lots of time.

Comment: A similar question, with solution:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/356497/select-points-falling-outside-of-buffer-and-count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two interacting things that might slow down your query:

- Trying to do a "all things disjoin" or "all things further" style query
- Using functional indexes

I have found in the past that using `col::geography` syntax does not play well with functional indexes, so using `geography(col)` in the query is required.

Counter-intuitively, finding "the things not" is frequently sped up by "finding the things that are" and then not returning them. So, like this:

```sql
SELECT locations.geom 
FROM locations
LEFT JOIN ways
ON ST_DWithin(
    geography(ways.linestring),
    geography(locations.geom),
    3)
WHERE ways.id IS NULL;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` nulls out the values of the right-hand relation in the join when the join condition is false, so this is a short-hand way to extract all the things that "don't" from a query.

Same idea, different implementation, might work better:

```sql
SELECT locations.geom
FROM locations
EXCEPT 
SELECT locations.geom 
FROM ways
JOIN locations
ON ST_DWithin(
    geography(ways.linestring),
    geography(locations.geom),
    3)
```